# Подключение к бд в зависимости от домена

Tags: php, база-данных, sql

Здравствуйте.

Как можно организовать подключение к нужной бд в зависимости от сайта, на который мы зашли?
Допустим, есть сайты:
test1.site.ru
test2.site.ru
test3.site.ru

и общий файл конфигурации, и в нем данные о подключении. Я поняла, что сделать это можно через `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`.
Получится, бд, к которой подключаемся, должна иметь имя, что и адрес сайта.
Есть ли еще какие варианты?

Comment: @aa22, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать такой костыль.

```
// Ассоциативный массив с именем БД, такие же можно создать для пароля и юзера
$data = array(
    'site1.ru' => 'db_name1',
    'site2.ru' => 'db_name2',
    'site3.ru' => 'db_name2'
);
// Текущий домен
$current_site = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
// Текущие имя базы данных
$get_current_dbname = $data[$current_site];
```

Но я бы не стал использовать такую архитектуру :)

Comment: Как такое сделать, я знаю. ) Мне бы узнать, есть ли еще варианты.

Comment: @aa22 заведите отдельные приложения и каждому дайте по базе ;)